# Access parent's parent from javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop

Something like

```
var life= {
        users : {
             guys : function(){ this.SOMETHING.mameAndDestroy(this.girls); },
             girls : function(){ this.SOMETHING.kiss(this.boys); },
        },
        mameAndDestroy : function(group){ },
        kiss : function(group){ }
};
```

this.SOMETHING is what I imagine the format is, but it might not be. What will step back up to the parent of an object?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

JavaScript does not offer this functionality natively.  And I doubt you could even create this type of functionality.  For example:

```
var Bobby = {name: "Bobby"};
var Dad = {name: "Dad", children: [ Bobby ]};
var Mom = {name: "Mom", children: [ Bobby ]};
```

Who does Bobby belong to?

Comment: This is much clearer example of the anomalies associated with multiple parents than the selected answer.

Comment: Well, if we want Mom and Dad to have the same properties and methods, I think we can achieve the desired functionality through abstracting away the declaration of parents and the setting of their children. What are your thoughts on the following fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/whrom/nP5eM/

Comment: The original question is how to get from an object to its "container." I gave an example of an object with two "containers." Your example introduces multiple containers on both sides of the relationship. This doesn't solve the original question, but it does demonstrate even further the complexities of such a simple concept.  For example, (using your code) if the child's "parent" collection gets out of sync with the parent's "children" collection, you'll have a real problem.

Comment: "And I doubt you could even create this type of functionality." you just go Bobby.father=Dad. And I wouldn't have the Dad's name be "Dad", thats confusing. "Joe" or just some usual name would be better.

Answer (score 61):

I simply added in first function

```
parentThis = this;
```

and use parentThis in subfunction. Why? Because in JavaScript, objects are soft. A new member can be added to a soft object by simple assignment (not like ie. Java where classical objects are hard. The only way to add a new member to a hard object is to create a new class) More on this here: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

And also at the end you don't have to kill or destroy the object. Why I found here: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/152552-javascript-destroy-object

Hope this helps

Comment: Super late here, but can someone elaborate with a code sample? I'm not seeing how this helps in an object like the OP's code.

Comment: I'm  surprised that this answer is the most upvoted here. Who is the "first function"? It works when the object is a function (as in tntu answer), but not when the object is a static object as in the OP's question! The parentThis will return the `Window` object

Comment: absolutely useful! thank you, you saved a lot of my time!

Answer (score 19):

In this case, you could use `life` to reference the parent object. Or you could store a reference to `life` in the users object. There can't be a fixed `parent` available to you in the language, because users is just a reference to an object, and there could be other references...

```
var death = { residents : life.users };
life.users.smallFurryCreaturesFromAlphaCentauri = { exist : function() {} };
// death.residents.smallFurryCreaturesFromAlphaCentauri now exists
//  - because life.users references the same object as death.residents!
```

You might find it helpful to use something like this:

```
function addChild(ob, childName, childOb)
{
   ob[childName] = childOb;
   childOb.parent = ob;
}

var life= {
        mameAndDestroy : function(group){ },
        kiss : function(group){ }
};

addChild(life, 'users', {
   guys : function(){ this.parent.mameAndDestroy(this.girls); },
   girls : function(){ this.parent.kiss(this.boys); },
   });

// life.users.parent now exists and points to life
```

Comment: it seems all objects could have the parent member, and this might simply be null or an empty object if it dosen't exist.. that would make it possible to use a sort of polymorphism when you move objects between other objects... 

or is this just a silly concept?

Comment: Robert, in the example i gave, who would be the parent - life, or death? You're free to store a reference to the parent object and give it any name you want - but it's up to you to enforce a single-parent structure.

Comment: I see that now, thanks --- JavaScript is pretty incredibly expressive, this is just another example of that :)

Answer (score 5):

#### About Call:

You can sort of solve this issue by using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which:

- must be called on a function `addName.call()`
- you pass it an object of what you want to be the "this" `addName.call({"name" : 'angela'});`
- you can pass additional arguments that can be used in the function it is called on `addName.call({"name": "angela"}, true);` where perhaps `addName` accepts an argument of boolean `append`.

#### Use Call:

For this particular problem, we can pass the "parent" object through `call` to override the `this` normally present in the child object.

#### Look at our problem first

```
var app = {
    init: function() {
        var _this = this; // so we can access the app object in other functions

        $('#thingy').click(function(){
            alert(_this.options.thingy());
        });

        $('#another').click(function(){
            alert(_this.options.getAnother());
        });
    },
    options: {
      thingy: function() {
      // PROBLEM: the this here refers to options
        return this.getThingy();
      },
      getAnother: function() {
        // PROBLEM 2: we want the this here to refer to options,
        // but thingy will need the parent object
        return 'another ' + this.thingy();
      },
    },
    getThingy: function() {
        return 'thingy';
    }
};
```

#### Now, here's a solution use call

And [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hL65m2ed/) to see it work.

```
var app = {
    init: function() {
        var _this = this; // so we can access the app object in other functions

        $('#thingy').click(function(){
            // SOLUTION: use call to pass _this as the 'this' used by thingy
            alert(_this.options.thingy.call(_this));
        });

        $('#another').click(function(){
            // SOLUTION 2: Use call to pass parent all the way through
            alert(_this.options.getAnother.call(_this)); 
        });
    },
    options: {
      thingy: function() {
        // SOLUTION in action, the this is the app object, not options.
        return this.getThingy(); 
      },
      getAnother: function() {
        // SOLUTION 2 in action, we can still access the options 
        // AND pass through the app object to the thingy method.
        return 'another ' + this.options.thingy.call(this); 
      },
    },
    getThingy: function() {
        return 'thingy';
    }
};
```

#### In conclusion

You can use `.call()` whenever you use a method on a property of your main object: `app.options.someFunction(arg)` should always be called with `.call` - `app.options.someFunction.call(this, arg);` - that way you can ensure that you'll always have access to every part of the object. It could give you access to another property's methods like `app.helpers.anotherFunction()`.

A good idea is in the `somefunction`, store `this` in a variable `_parentThis` so it's obvious what the `this` reflects.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading your question correctly, objects in general are agnostic about where they are contained.  They don't know who their parents are.  To find that information, you have to parse the parent data structure.  The DOM has ways of doing this for us when you're talking about element objects in a document, but it looks like you're talking about vanilla objects.

Comment: that's how I understood it -- I figured I may have just not been aware of a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
var life={
        users:{
             guys:function(){ life.mameAndDestroy(life.users.girls); },
             girls:function(){ life.kiss(life.users.guys); }
        },
        mameAndDestroy : function(group){ 
          alert("mameAndDestroy");
          group();
        },
        kiss : function(group){
          alert("kiss");
          //could call group() here, but would result in infinite loop
        }
};

life.users.guys();
life.users.girls();
```

Also, make sure you don't have a comma after the "girls" definition. This will cause the script to crash in IE (any time you have a comma after the last item in an array in IE it dies).

[See it run](http://jsbin.com/icoga/edit)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it is not possible to directly lookup a parent from a nested child. All of the proposed solutions advise various different ways of referring back to the parent object or parent scope through an explicit variable name.

However, directly traversing up to the the parent object is possible if you employ recursive [ES6 Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) on the parent object.

I've written a library called [ObservableSlim](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim) that, among other things, allows you to traverse up from a child object to the parent.

Here's a simple example ([jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hp0h5g8v/)):

```
var test = {"hello":{"foo":{"bar":"world"}}};
var proxy = ObservableSlim.create(test, true, function() { return false });

function traverseUp(childObj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(childObj.__getParent())); // returns test.hello: {"foo":{"bar":"world"}}
    console.log(childObj.__getParent(2)); // attempts to traverse up two levels, returns undefined because test.hello does not have a parent object
};

traverseUp(proxy.hello.foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used something that resembles singleton pattern:

```
function myclass() = {
    var instance = this;

    this.Days = function() {
        var days = ["Piątek", "Sobota", "Niedziela"];
        return days;
    }

    this.EventTime = function(day, hours, minutes) {
        this.Day = instance.Days()[day];
        this.Hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.TotalMinutes = day*24*60 + 60*hours + minutes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this and it works like a charm.

Simple.

P.S. There is more the the object but I just posted the relevant part.

```
var exScript = (function (undefined) {
    function exScript() {
        this.logInfo = [];
        var that = this;
        this.logInfo.push = function(e) {
            that.logInfo[that.logInfo.length] = e;
            console.log(e);
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can access the parent of the object:

```
var Users = function(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
};
Users.prototype.guys = function(){ 
    this.parent.nameAndDestroy(['test-name-and-destroy']);
};
Users.prototype.girls = function(){ 
    this.parent.kiss(['test-kiss']);
};

var list = {
    users : function() {
        return new Users(this);
    },
    nameAndDestroy : function(group){ console.log(group); },
    kiss : function(group){ console.log(group); }
};

list.users().guys(); // should output ["test-name-and-destroy"]
list.users().girls(); // should output ["test-kiss"]
```

I would recommend you read about javascript [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) to get to know how you can work with Objects, it helped me a lot. I even found out about functions that I didn't even knew they existed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all parents key of a node in a literal object (`{}`), you can to do that:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $.defineProperties($, {
        parentKeys: {
            value: function (object) {
                var
                    traces = [],
                    queue = [{trace: [], node: object}],

                    block = function () {
                        var
                            node,
                            nodeKeys,
                            trace;

                        // clean the queue
                        queue = [];
                        return function (map) {
                            node = map.node;
                            nodeKeys = Object.keys(node);

                            nodeKeys.forEach(function (nodeKey) {
                                if (typeof node[nodeKey] == "object") {
                                    trace = map.trace.concat(nodeKey);
                                    // put on queue
                                    queue.push({trace: trace, node: node[nodeKey]});

                                    // traces.unshift(trace);
                                    traces.push(trace);
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    };

                while(true) {
                    if (queue.length) {
                        queue.forEach(block());
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return traces;
            },

            writable: true
        }

    });

})(Object);
```

This algorithm uses the `FIFO` concept for iterate the graphs using the `BFS` method. This code extend the class `Object` adding the static method `parentKeys` that expects a `literal Object` (hash table - associative array...) of the Javacript, as parameter.

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the structure of the object because it's given to you (typically from a library), you can alway traverse recursively the object to find its parent.

```js
/**
 * Recursively traverse the rootObject to find the parent of childObject.
 * @param rootObject - root object to inspect
 * @param childObject - child object to match
 * @returns - parent object of child if exists, undefined otherwise
 */
function findParent(rootObject, childObject) {
  if (!(rootObject && typeof rootObject === 'object')) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(rootObject)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rootObject.length; i++) {
      if (rootObject[i] === childObject) {
        return rootObject;
      }
      const child = this.findParent(rootObject[i], childObject);
      if (child) {
        return child;
      }
    }
  } else {
    const keys = Object.keys(rootObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
      const key = keys[i];
      if (rootObject[key] === childObject) {
        return rootObject;
      }
      const child = this.findParent(rootObject[key], childObject);
      if (child) {
        return child;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

// tests

const obj = {
  l1: { l11: { l111: ['a', 'b', 'c'] } },
  l2: { l21: ['a', 1, {}], l22: 123 },
  l3: [ { l33: {} } ],
};

assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l1), obj);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l1.l11), obj.l1);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l2), obj);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l2.l21), obj.l2);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l2.l22), obj.l2);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l3[0]), obj.l3);
assert.equal(findParent(obj, obj.l3[0].l33), obj.l3[0]);
```