# Wrapping objects in JS (best practices)

Tags: javascript

Was looking through best practices when dealing with external objects for example and ran across this article about [why not to modify objects you do not own.](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Reasoning is fairly sound, my question is how would I go about implementing this. For reference my code behaviour is current like this (custom object being owned by a 3rd party, Google maps):

```
var cObj = new customObject();
//I need to custom properties in addition to what Google provides
//So I insert new properties:
cObj.myProp1 = 1;
```

Article gives good reasons as to why its a bad practice therefore I do this:

```
function objWrapper(e){
   var cObj = e.cObj ? e.cObj : null;
   var myProp1 = e.myProp1 ? e.myProp1 : null;
}

//Here I create a copy of my wrapper and insert the Custom Object into it:
var obj - new objWrapper({});
var cObj = new customObject();

//Then I insert the cObj reference to the wrapper
obj.cObj = cObj;
```

This approach works fine when dealing with just variables but if say I ever need to access another child of the obj I would need to add in a circular reference like so:

```
cObj.obj = obj;
```

Which is not ideal, with a OO language I can see how to do this properly, not quite sure how to proceed in JS. I don't see how prototypes would really help here either.

PS: The actual code I'm working with is [here](https://github.com/boarnoah/boarnoah.github.io/blob/master/assets/js/boarnoah.map.js) but a more generalised explanation is what I'm looking for.

Comment: quick question: how to do it properly with an OO language?

Comment: @LimH. I was thinking along the lines of C#/Haxe where you would access the parent through super. etc... It appears JS has no such upwards relationship natively: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789909/4433646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that new thing for the wrapper. for objects you can just use { }.

```
var obj = new customObject();

var wrapper = { 'childobj' : obj, 'anotherProperty': 1 };
console.log(wrapper.childobj);
```

Comment: How does accessing the wrapper's anotherProperty from a function from obj work.
 // later in the code:
 obj.addListener('click', function(){
  //Here I would prefer having access to wrapper's other children/functions
  console.log(wrapper.anotherProperty);
  console.log(wrapper.anotherFunction());
 });

In say C#, Haxe etc.. I would use a keyword base/super to access this parent. Or this that 
considered bad practice to begin with (I see it a lot with with Frameworks, Unity for example). Code here(SO comments are bad =( ): https://gist.github.com/boarnoah/df88d579d5f5ca8bc42b

Comment: obj.parent = wrapper; (after you've wrapped it).then console.log(obj.parent.anotherProperty); note however that if you have a circular reference like that, you won't be able to stringify it to json.