# How to change scope of JavaScript getter?

Tags: javascript, scope, this, getter

Given the following object:

```
var myObj = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',
    values: {
        get fullName() {
            return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname
        }
    }
};
```

When trying to access `myObj.values.fullName`, `undefined undefined` is returned because the context of `this` is set to `myObj.values`, not `myObj`.

Is there a way to change that? I tried every combination of `bind` I can think of, but most of the time this just results in syntax error because `fullName` isn't a regular function.

Comment: Can't you use it like `return myObj.fname + ' ' + myObj.lname` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to parent object properties only by `myObj.fname` and `myObj.lname`.

```
var myObj = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',
    values: {
        get fullName() {
            return myObj.fname + ' ' + myObj.lname
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot access parent objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript). Do you need to nest the getter within the values element? The following would work just fine:

```
var myObj = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',
    get fullName() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname
    }
};

alert(myObj.fullName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "this" with the name of the object

OPTION 1:

```
var myObj = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',
    values: {
        get fullName() {
            return myObj.fname + ' ' + myObj.lname
        }
    }
};
```

Another alternative:

OPTION 2:

```
var myObj = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',
    values: {
        get fullName() {
            return this.parent.fname + ' ' + this.parent.lname
        }
    },
    init: function(){
        this.values.parent = this;
        delete this.init; 
        return this;
    }
}.init()
```

Comment: Would this work if there are multiple instances of the `myObj` object?

Comment: It is a good point. It works out with the second option (edited in original post)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Will my answer was satisfactory for you?

Comment: I think so. It's very similar to the revealing module pattern.