# Different this in Object.defineProperty getter in safari devtools, browser bug?

Tags: javascript, safari, google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

Run this code in the console in Safari (15.1) and another browser (eg. Brave/Chrome):

```
const a = {b: {c: 5}}
Object.defineProperty(a.b, 'self', {get () {return this}})
console.log(a.b.self) // expected: {c: 5}
console.log(a) // when expanding a.b.self in inspector, expects the same, ie. {c: 5}
```

Then, expand the last object, until you get `self: (...)`, now, expanding it should be equivalent to running `a.b.self`? It is in Brave, but I get the `a` object in Safari.

Hypothesis: Safari devtools has a bug where it uses the object logged, and not the prop parent, as `this`.

Or is this UB and I've gotten something wrong?

[image: safari result]
[image: brave results]

Comment: `this` changes depending on how the method is called. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197822/how-does-this-work-in-javascript -- since a getter is being used, I'm not sure what `this` should be

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956688/how-to-change-scope-of-javascript-getter seems to suggest that `this` is not reliable in a getter.

Comment: @evolutionxbox in this case the new property is being defined on `a.b`, so `this` should refer to that object and it's not weird.

Comment: @Pointy that's good to know

Comment: OP, don't be fooled by console behavior. There is no standard, and each browser console has its own ideas of how it can make your life better. They are not consistent.