# Setting an object's property value using object's method

Tags: javascript, oop

Is There any way to set object property using object function?
 Eg:

```
var Object={
    init: function(){
        this.newParam=alert("ok");// This should alert ok while called     Object.newParam()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't get called as per your expectation. It would get called during the time when the object is getting initialized. And `obj.newParam` would have the returned value of `alert("ok")`, i.e] `undefined`.

You have to rewrite your code like below to achieve what you want,

```
var obj = {
 init: function(){
  this.newParam= function() { 
    alert("ok");// This should alert ok while called Object.newParam()
  }
 }
}
```

Also using name `Object` for your variable is a riskier one when you are in the global context.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var Object={
        init: function(){
            return {
                newParam :function() {
                alert("ok");// This should alert ok while called Object.newParam()
             }
        }
        }
}
console.debug(Object.init().newParam());
```

Note that when init() is called it returns an object. You can use that object and invoke newParam function from that - `Object.init().newParam()`

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/krwxoumL/

Comment: I don't want that. I want to have Object.newparam in place of Object.init().newparam But I don't want to set its value manually using `newparam: this.init().newparam`

Comment: ok, not sure if I understood it correctly but looks like it's something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript