# How can I reference the parent object in a child function?

Tags: javascript

Given an object like this:

```
var MyObj = {
  bar: 10,
  foo: function() {
     alert(MyObj.bar);
  }
}
```

How can I generically reference `MyObj` from `MyObj.foo` such that if I were to change `var MyObj` to `var MyObj2` I wouldn't need to modify the `foo` function?

Comment: Use `this` instead of `MyObj`.

Comment: Depending on execution context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access parent object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `this.bar` doesn't work if do `MyObj.foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat `MyObj` like a class, you could do something like what [lumio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673759/2123956) suggested, or you could do something like

```
function MyObj(){
    this.bar = 10;
    this.foo = function(){ 
        return this.bar; 
    }
}
var a = new MyObj();
var b = new MyObj();
b.bar = 5;
console.log(a.foo(), b.foo()) // 10 5
```

If instead, you just want to reference the object's `bar` value, then you could just replace the `alert(MyObj.bar);` with `alert(this.bar);`

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I need.  I'm not really trying to do real "class" logic -- just want to namespace some helper functions more or less.  If I have nested structures (`MyObj.foo.bar.baz.func1();`), I'm thinking I can do `var that = this;` right at the top of the function and then `that` will always reference parent no matter where I am

Answer (score 0):

Classes would help you a lot here. In ES5 classes can be created like so:

```js
function MyObj() {
  this.bar = 10;
}
MyObj.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log( this.bar );
}

var objInstance = new MyObj;
objInstance.foo();

var objInstance2 = new MyObj;
objInstance2.bar = 20;
objInstance2.foo();
```

---

ES6 allows an even better notation:

```js
class MyObj {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 10;
  }
  
  foo() {
    console.log( this.bar );
  }
}

var objInstance = new MyObj;
objInstance.foo();

var objInstance2 = new MyObj;
objInstance2.bar = 20;
objInstance2.foo();
```

Use babel to convert it to ES5.