# Method chaining in es5 classes

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

```
CurrentUser = function (){}
CurrentUser.prototype = {
    record: undefined
}
CurrentUser.prototype.is = {
    get _parent() {return CurrentUser.prototype},

    get signedIn() {
        return !!this._parent.record
    }
}
User = new CurrentUser
User.record = {name:'Joe'}
User.is.signedIn //false
```

What I'm trying to do here is create a new User, give him some data (record) and based on that determine that he is signedIn (if his record has data - he is signedIn).

But what happens in reality is that `User.is.signedIn` getter is accessing `CurrentUser.prototype` instead of accessing `User` instance. And as `CurrentUser.prototype.record` is `undefined` - `User.is.signedIn` returns `false`.

Comment: `User.record` has nothing to do with `CurrentUser.prototype.record`.  You can't do that.

Comment: SLaks, can you recommend smth to achieve what I want here?

Comment: There is no simple way to chain objects like that.  Don't do that.

Comment: Why not `user.isSignedIn` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript objects: get parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Comment: "*`get _parent() {return CurrentUser.prototype},`*" - waat? Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this (saw Bergi's answer after I've found a solution)

```
CurrentUser.prototype = {
    record: undefined,
    get is() { return {
        _parent: this,
        get signedIn() {return !!this._parent.record}
    }}
}

User = new CurrentUser
User.record = {name:'Joe'}
User.is.signedIn //true
```

We make `is` getter return an object that holds a reference to `CurrentUser.prototype` via assigning this to `_parent`. And this object in turn has its own getters that when accessing `_parent` gain access to `CurrentUser.prototype`. Voila!
Btw, if you have many other methods\getters inside the `is` getter - you can refactor it out into a standalone object and then add it to `CurrentUser.prototype` via `Object.defineProperty()`.

PS
Many advised against chaining class methods but nobody could say ***why***.
I like my code to be as close to human language as possible - and `User.is.signedIn` just looks better to me than `User.isSignedIn`; I also put many other `is`-related checks inside the `is` method - so they don't clutter up `User` namespace.

Comment: Why not to use this? Because it's inefficient to create so many objects on the fly. Natural language can be useful on occasion (e.g. in a testing framework) but actually your code should reflect your data structures, not human languages. There is no clutter on the `User` namespace (if there is, all it does mean is that you should split up the class, not introduce punctuation in the method names), and the `.is` property on its own is pretty meaningless. Why not also use `User.is.signed.in` and `User.is.signed.out`? There's a good reason we pull them together.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=code+micro+optimization
First 5 articles advise for code readability versus micro optimizations

Comment: Your solution is the same as @Bergi's, It would have been better if you edited his answer with the code explanation.

Comment: @avalanche1 I would argue that it's not a *micro* optimisation but a pretty substantial one. Als the readability of the call (`user.is.signed.in` vs `user.isSignedIn`) doesn't differ a lot, while the readability of the property/method declaration takes a decent hit.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for

```
CurrentUser = function (){}
CurrentUser.prototype = {
    record: undefined,
    get is() {
        var parent = this;
        return {
            get signedIn() {
                return !!parent.record;
            }
        };
    }
};
var user = new CurrentUser
user.record = {name:'Joe'}
user.is.signedIn // true
```

However I would really recommend to avoid this. Put a simple `isSignedIn()` method on the prototype and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class CurrentUser {
   constructor(){
    this.record = null; 
   }

   get isSignedIn(){
     return !!this.record;
   }

 }

const user = new CurrentUser;
console.log( user.isSignedIn );

user.record = {what:"ever"};
console.log(user.isSignedIn);
```

Simply put the getter inside the prototype itself and not into a subobject.

Comment: @avalanche1 no you don't want to. Theres no advantage of it, just disadvantages

Comment: "one can easily read the “chainable” code, effortlessly type it, and comfortably understand it." - quote from http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/

Comment: @avalanche1 *chaining **methods*** is a different thing

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no way.

Workaround 1 (using the `call` method to tweak the `this` binding rules):

```js
    function Foo() {
    this.x = 10; 
    }
    
    Foo.prototype.bar = {
    baz: function() {
    return this.x; 
    } 
    };
    
    var y = new Foo();
    
    console.log(y["bar"]["baz"].call(y));
```

Workaround 2 (we add a reference to the instantiated object to `Foo.prototype.bar` upon instantiation):

```js
function Foo() {
Foo.prototype.bar._this = this;
this.x = 10;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = {
baz: function() {
return this._this.x; 
} 
};

var y = new Foo();

console.log(y["bar"]["baz"]());
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent) question, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript).