# converting a dot.delimited object reference to a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, object, object-reference

I've looked everywhere, and it seems like the kind of thing that should be simple, so forgive me if this IS simple or violates best practices or I just missed it.

I want to be able to convert an object reference into a string. Not the object being referred to, but the reference itself.

Let's say I have a method nested in an object, for example:

```
a.b.c.d()
```

where a is the object and d is the method, how do I retrieve the string:

`"a.b.c.d"` ?

To be a little more specific, I want to pass the object reference as an argument to a function and be able to convert it to a string representing the key path:

```
function convertPath ( a.b.c.d ) {
    ...
}
```

could return the string `"a.b.c.d"`. (I'd perform some other operations with it instead of just returning it, but I'm keeping this simple.)

Methods like "toString", etc. return the actual function being referenced as a string.

I've seen plenty of references to do the opposite (pass a string and convert it to an object reference), which would create other complications for me, but not this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: According to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript), it's not possible to access the parent object from within a nested object

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm afraid I don't understand. I'm not trying to access the parent object. I'm just trying to take the argument being passed (a.b.c.d) and reproduce it as a string ("a.b.c.d").

Comment: If you pass `a.b.c.d`, you only have this `d` object. There is no information about `a b c` so you cannot convert this path into a string. You'd need access to `a` in order to know the path to `d` is `a.b.c.d`

Comment: What do you need to do this for? If you explain why you think you need `"a.b.c.d"`, you'll probably get a much more useful answer.

Comment: I need access to both string and object reference. Some keys in the object references in my code are represented by abstractions that return a value. So receiving a string as an argument and converting it to the object ref gets a little complicated. I can work it out but I thought it might be simpler to just receive the object ref and convert it to a string. 

But I get Jannes Carpentier's response - it seemed to me that if you're passing the keypath as an argument, the info about a b and c is right there but I get that that's not how it works. I'll go the other route. Thanks to you both.

Comment: You COULD pass "a.b.c.d" to the function as, say `path`, and to actually get d, use `eval(path)`...  You probably SHOULDN'T do it...
(and to eval, say, "a.b.c" from `path`, you could: `path=path.split(".");path.pop();path=path.join("."); eval(path);`)
Repeating other's question: Why?

Comment: I tried to answer the question "why" in the response to Patrick's question, if that's not clear it would be helpful for me to understand if I didn't describe it properly. I went the route I mentioned there instead, passing in the argument as a string and converting it to an object reference. It's stated practically everywhere that eval should be avoided so I excluded it form consideration. Thanks for your input.