# javascript using this in a child method

Tags: javascript

Method:

```js
a = {
  foo: 1,
  bar() {
    return this.foo + 1
  },
  lol: {
    baz() {
      return this.foo
    }
  }
}
```

`a.bar()` this which refers to a which is what I want. I'm looking for a way for the child method inside a.lol.baz to also have this refer to a. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access parent object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to it directly. But you can bind the function to the object explicitly, then `this` will be available.

```js
a = {
  foo: 1,
  bar() {
    return this.foo + 1
  },
  lol: {}
}

a.lol.baz = (function() {
  return this.foo
}).bind(a);

console.log(a.lol.baz());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `a.lol.baz.call(a)` function

```js
a = {
  foo: 1,
  bar() {
    return this.foo + 1
  },
  lol: {
    baz() {

      return this.foo
    }
  }
}
var res=a.lol.baz.call(a)
alert(res)
```