# Is there a way to do run something from a parent of a parent?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access parent's parent from javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object)

Im a bit confused how to say this but i want what i would expect from the code "this.this.".

In the array

```
Foo = 
{
    bar : 
    {
        Tool : function()
        {
            return this.this.foofoo;
        },
    },
    foofoo : "rawr"
}
```

From the function Foo.bar.Tool() how can i get it to access the data foofoo ?

Thankyou !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you can't.

`this` doesn't work like you might expect -- it refers to the object that you're calling the function on behalf of, and has nothing to do with *where* the function was defined.

So for example:

```
var blah = { prop: 'blahprop' };
var cow = {
   cowfunc: function() {
       alert(this.prop);    // Notice there's no 'prop' in cow
   }
};

blah.blahfunc = cow.cowfunc;
blah.blahfunc();         // alerts 'blahprop'
```

If you want that behaviour, you'll need to pass in `foofoo` (or its parent).

Alternatively, you can initialize `Foo` as in your question, then set a reference on `bar` to `Foo`:

```
Foo.bar.Foo = Foo;
```

Then, assuming you're calling `Tool` on `bar`, you can change `Tool` to read:

```
Tool: function() {
    return this.Foo.foofoo;   // 'this' refers to bar when called like bar.Tool()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the parent object literally:

```
Foo = 
{
    bar : 
    {
        Tool : function()
        {
            return Foo.foofoo;
        },
    },
    foofoo : "rawr"
}

alert(Foo.bar.Tool()); // alerts "rawr"
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, variables (and properties of objects) *reference* values; they do not *contain* them. consider this code:

```
var foo = { message:"hello" };
var bar1 = { o:foo };
var bar2 = { b:foo };
```

In the above, `bar1.o` is the same object as `bar2.a`. Both you might consider the "parent" of `foo`, which is there is no information on the name or ownership of any value.

You cannot do what you want with the data structure you have. You need to either provide explicit pointers back to the "parent", or use a *closure* around a local variable.