# Get parent object within jQuery callbacks

Tags: javascript

This is my issue:

```
var greatapp = {
  start : function(){
    $.AJAX({
      url : 'foo.com',
      success : function(data){
        greatapp.say(data);
      }
    })
  },

  say : function(s){
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

What i don't like about this example is the fact that i repeat my self in the `success` function by defining the object's name instead of just `this` which obviously won't work because it's in an *external* function.

How to only have the name `greatapp` one time in a JS object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common JavaScript idiom is to save the value of `this` into a variable like `me` or `self`, and use *that* in the callback.

This will work since the callback has access to the variables declared in the enclosing scope—in other words the callback will form a closure over `self`

```
var greatapp = {
  start : function(){
    var self = this;
    $.AJAX({
      url : 'foo.com',
      success : function(data){
        self.say(data);
      }
    })
  },

  say : function(s){
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```