# Is there a way to inspect the parent/calling object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

Given this setup:

```
var ObjectNamespace   = {}
var FunctionNamespace = function FunctionNamespace() {}

ObjectNamespace.User = function() {}
FunctionNamespace.User = function User() {}
```

Is there anyway to write a `namespace` method to accomplish something like this:

```
ObjectNamespace.User.namespace() //=> "ObjectNamespace.User"
FunctionNamespace.User.namespace() //=> "FunctionNamespace.User"
```

You can get the first node by doing something like this:

```
ObjectNamespace.User.namespace = function() {
  return this.toString().match(/function *(\w+)/)[1]
}

ObjectNamespace.User.namespace() //=> "User"
```

But my question is, is there a way to reference the "parent" object, i.e. the object the `User` function is defined on (`ObjectNamespace`)?  Something meta along the lines of `arguments.caller.callee`.  That way you'd get this:

```
ObjectNamespace.User.namespace() //=> "ObjectNamespace.User"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not. Let's assume there was, and we call it by `*.parent`. What would the following code do:

```
var apple = {}, banana = {}, lemon = {};
banana.friend = apple.friend = lemon;

lemon.parent.otherThing = 6;

console.log(apple.otherThing, banana.otherThing);

// 6, undefined?
// undefined, 6?
// 6, 6?
```

Who is `lemon`'s parent? Both `apple` and `banana` are, but that doesn't make sense...

Also, your idea, while good, won't work if you call the namespace function out of context.

Answer (score 0):

There once was [`__parent__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Parent), but it's been removed. I'm not sure how it worked, see davins answer.

You might also have a look at [Access parent's parent from javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183702/1048572).