# how to access outer parent from inner object javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to access the Parent's attribute from inner() without its reference being passed explicitly to it (as I have to do in this code) ?

Here is my javascript code :

```
function Parent() {
return {
    outer: {
        parent: null,  //I want to avoid this
        name: 'outer',
        inner: function() {
            console.log(this.name);
            console.log(this.parent.name);   //how to access parent.name ?
        }
    },

    name: 'parent'

};
}

$(document).ready(function() {

var p = new Parent();
p.outer.parent = p;  //I want to avoid this
p.outer.inner();

});
```

Comment: It comes down to, You can't

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access parent's parent from javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the Parent's attribute from inner() without its reference being passed explicitly to it (as I have to do in this code) ?

No. There is no structure to objects other than name/value pairs, an object has no knowledge of things that reference it. Relationships are created entirely by assigning values to properties and work only in one direction: from a reference to an object.

The object literal:

```
var a = {foo: {bar:'bar'}};
```

is identical to:

```
var a = {};
a.foo = {bar:'bar'};
```

which is identical to:

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
b['bar'] = 'bar';
a['foo'] = b;
```

and any number of other similar formulations.

Answer (score -1):

You can ommit the p assignment by this:

```
function Parent() {
return {
    outer: {
        parent: this, //keep reference
        name: 'outer',
        inner: function() {
            console.log(this.name);
            console.log(this.parent.name);   //how to access parent.name ?
        }
    },

    name: 'parent'

};
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var p = new Parent();
    p.outer.inner();

});
```

But I guess it's not what you need.

Comment: No, that won't give access to outer's parent, and certainly not `parent.name` of the `p` object inside the `inner()` function.