# How to read the string value of a component's input attribute binding in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple form input component in my angular2 app which contains an `@Input` binding to the attribute `[dataProperty]`. As you may have guessed, the `[dataProperty]` attribute is a string value of the format: `[dataProperty]="modelObject.childObj.prop"`, where the `modelObject` is the model shared throughout my application. Basically, I'm using this `@Input` attribute to pass the model from a parent component to my `<custom-text-input>` component, where it is then bound by `[ngModel]` to the nested component's input.

Everything works as intended and in my controller; i.e. when I access `this.dataProperty` the value on the model to which the input binds is returned. What I can't seem to find out, however, is how to access the string literal passed to `[dataProperty]` from the template in the first place.

**Component:**

```
@Component{
    selector: "custom-text-input",
    template: "<input type="text" [ngModel]="dataProperty"></input>
}

export Class customInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataProperty: string;

    /**
       ex of modelObject: { detail: { name: "Cornelius" } }
       (^^^ would originate in parent component ^^^)
    */

    constructor() {}

}
```

**Use Case:**

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <custom-text-input [dataProperty]="modelObject.detail.name">
    </custom-text-input>
</div>
```

Basically, when I go to access `this.DataProperty` from the component controller it returns "Cornelius". Is it possible to access the string literal so that I can capture the `"modelObject.detail.name"` string from my controller as well?

Comment: Do you mean, you want retrieve 'modelObject.detail.name'? You want to know the name of the value being passed in, not the actual value?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a key-value pair of the property and it's name and pass them in together like so:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <custom-text-input [dataProperty]="{modelObject.detail.name}">
    </custom-text-input>
</div>
```

Then I would gain access to the property name by doing something like this:

```js
@Component{
    selector: "custom-text-input",
    template: "<input type="text" [ngModel]="dataProperty"></input>
}
export Class customInputComponent {

    dataPropertyName;

    private _dataProperty;    
    @Input() 
    set dataProperty( keyValuePair ){
      this._dataProperty = Object.values(keyValuePair)[0]
      this.dataPropertyName = Object.keys(keyValuePair)[0]
    }
    get dataProperty( ){
      console.log( "I have the property name here:" + this.dataPropertyName )
      return this._dataProperty
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this should be possible. But you have to think somewhat out of the box. The element with the dataProperty is, in the end, just a HTML node.

```
<custom-text-input [dataProperty]="modelObject.detail.name">
```

I'm not in a position at the moment to create an example for you, but you could simple get a reference to the components HTML (using Angular viewReference in your component) and simply query the attribute on it. Pseudo code would something like

```
 let myString = viewref.nativeElement.getAttribute('[dataProperty]')
```

Again, I haven't tested it, but I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: This unfortunately would not work, as the rendering converts the object into `[object Object]`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes. heres a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uJH17jhWxeJlfMjxUPoj but this does not even keep the input property in the DOM. I've seen it rendered multiple times as [object Object] though

Comment: Angular strips away all of your bound properties during compile time. You wouldn't even see [object Object] if you ran it in production mode.

Comment: Neh you're right. The original nodes from the template will only be added after compilation, than the original attribute is gone... Too bad.. Let's think some more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, angular 2 uses the default conversion from Object to string, in this case, and will only display the familiar `[object Object]` in the DOM. You cannot get more information out of that.

Also, the object does not know anything about its parent object. See: [Access parent's parent from javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object)

You could use something like Somo's answer: provide the value as a property of an object. The name of the property should be the string literal, the value of the property should be the actual value.

Use Case:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <custom-text-input [dataProperty]="{'modelObject.detail.name': modelObject.detail.name}">
    </custom-text-input>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component{
    selector: "custom-text-input",
    template: "<input type="text" [ngModel]="actualValue"></input>
}

export Class customInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataProperty: Object;
    actualValue: string;

    ngOnInit() { 
        console.log( Object.keys( dataProperty )[0] );
        console.log( Object.values( dataProperty )[0] );
        this.actualValue = Object.values( dataProperty )[0];
    ) }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

So it looks like the question is about printing the name of the variable instead of the value. **That's not possible.**

You can access the value from the controller:

```
export Class customInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataProperty: string; 

    constructor() {
       console.log(this.dataProperty) // would print modelObject.childObj.prop
    }

}
```

If your asking about Interpolation, you do this:

```
{{dataProperty}} <input type="text" [ngModel]="dataProperty"></input>
```

More info:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: It's not interpolation I'm looking for. I'm trying to access the string value passed to the input attribute from my controller for use with one of my services.

Comment: you've already done that haven't you using "this.DataProperty" in your child component. If you console log "this.DataProperty", it would print the value

Comment: I don't want the value since I already have it. I want the string literal i.e. "modelObject.detail.name". Also, interpolation isn't necessary because the ngModel directive already binds the model value to the text in the input

Comment: Not sure this is what John is asking for. He's asking how to get the *name* of the value being passed in, not the value.

Comment: You can't make the child component literary print "modelObject.detail.name", what good would that do

Comment: Hrmm... sounds he may be trying to track changes in various models. Have a list of what changed, tracked by name?