# I have trouble to display the API data to a label in a windows form

Tags: c#, json, winforms, api

I try to make a code to display organisms phylum, order, and kingdom, in `lblOrganismIdentity`. Firstly, the user must input the species name in the `tbNameSpecies`. And then click `btProcess` to run the method on Organism class. And the name is used to make the API link. The API data is in this [link](http://api.gbif.org/v1/species/match?&name=canis%20lupus) for example. I dont know how to make the data to become an array, and then display it to `lblOrganismIdentity`.

The exception error message is

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'`

The exception error occurs in this code

`JsonObject kingdom = (JsonObject)gbifObj["kingdom"];`

I'm using RestSharp and SimpleJson for the references. I've tried to search for the solutions, but I didn't get that.

This is the source code.

The GetOrganismList method in Organism.cs class

```
public static List<string> GetOrganismList(string link)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
        var client = new RestClient(link);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        JsonObject gbifObj = (JsonObject)SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(gbifObj); 
        JsonObject kingdom = (JsonObject)gbifObj["kingdom"];
        JsonObject phylum = (JsonObject)gbifObj["phylum"];
        JsonObject order = (JsonObject)gbifObj["order"];
        returnList.Add((string)kingdom["kingdom"]);
        returnList.Add((string)phylum["phylum"]);
        returnList.Add((string)order["order"]);
        return returnList;
    }
```

Form1.cs

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> identityList = new List<string>();
    private IEnumerable<string> identitylist;

    private void btProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayInfo(identityList);

    }

    private void DisplayInfo(List<string> identityList)
    {
        string link = "http://api.gbif.org/v1/species/match?&name=" + tbNameSpecies.Text.ToString();
        identityList = Organism.GetOrganismList(link);
        lblOrganismIdentity.Text = "";
        foreach (string item in identityList)
        {
            lblOrganismIdentity.Text += "- " + item + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I expect the `lblOrganismIdentity` can display data of the species from the user input. 
For example:

kingdom: Animalia

phylum: Chordata

order: Carnivora

Comment: Hi! It would be very helpful to see what specific line you were getting that exception on. Additionally, if possible, could you provide a sample of the JSON the request is returning? The issue might be in the parser.

Comment: Is that JSON structure always the same or can it contain different properties? If it's constant (or some of the properties are) deserialize it to a class structure and use that class with standard .Net methods. If you need to show specific results as text, you can insert one or more overrides of `ToString()` and return a *sum* of the properties values you need. Note that Visual Studio allows to `Paste Special => Paste JSON as classes`. That JSON is quite simple, so it won't mess up the result :)

Comment: @FlutterDashie oh sorry i forgot to put where the exception error occurs. I've edited the post.

Comment: @salomohutapea Thank you much! This leads me to believe that the issue is somewhere in either the JSON or the parser. Do you have a piece of sample JSON on hand? The exception along with its location seems to reflect that the data is being pulled in, but that it does not have a `"kingdom"` field, or that said field is not visible from the first layer of the JSON.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks . I'll try it first.

Comment: @FlutterDashie it has kingdom field by the way. But i dont know what you mean that field is not visible from the first layer of the JSON. Actually i'm new to this API things, so I don't really understand.

Comment: @salomohutapea No worries. What I mean by first layer is that the field is not inside of any other field or array, or has no "parent". [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object) delves a little bit into the parent-child relationship in JSON. The reason this is relevant is that `gbifObj[<name>]` will only work if `<name>` exists and is not inside any other node/field/data item.

Comment: @Jimi After I paste special, what i'm going to do next? Am I going to make a new object to that class?

Comment: That class is the target of the deserialization. For example, if you name the class `Organism`, then: `var myOrganisms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Organism>([JSON string]);`. After that, you can access the class properties as usual.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your help. Now I can display the data.

Comment: @FlutterDashie thanks for your help too. Now I know a little bit about the concept of API.

Comment: @salomohutapea That's great to hear! If you would, could you answer the question with what you found and then accept the answer? That way, anyone else who has a similar problem will know what they can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work in a simple console app by Deserializing to expected object: 
notice i displayed value in a console app since i couldn't be bothered to create a new win form:

create a class for the return object. It's more clean.

```
class Animal {
    public int usageKey { get; set; }
    public int acceptedUsageKey { get; set; }
    public string scientificName { get; set; }
    public string canonicalName { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int confidence { get; set; }
    public string matchType { get; set; }
    public string kingdom { get; set; }
    public string phylum { get; set; }
    public int kingdomKey { get; set; }
    public int phylumKey { get; set; }
    public bool synonym { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method to get the value from api and do something with it

```
async void AsyncToConsole(Uri uri, Action<Animal> action) {

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var getReg = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var json = await getReg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
        Animal animal;
        try
        {
            animal = (SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Animal>(json));
            action(animal);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            action(new Animal() { kingdom = "error", confidence = 0, phylum = "error" });
        }
    }
}
```

Main method, kinda like your form click event handler

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var species = "Lycopodiophyta";
    var uri = new Uri($"http://api.gbif.org/v1/species/match?&name={ species }");

    // callable method to display the values. like your foreach loop
    // it will be passed to the async method, who will then call it instead.
    Action<Animal> populateLabel = (Animal animal) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"- {animal.kingdom}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- {animal.phylum}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- {animal.rank}");
    };
    // I need to use new Program(), but you dont need to do that
    new Program().AsyncToConsole(uri, populateLabel );
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

Comment: @salomohutapea glad to help. If it solved your question , then please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You must first deserialize the JSON to a class, for example `Organism` class. Copy first our JSON file example. And then, we can use `Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste JSON as classes`.

So The class will be like this.

```
public class Organism
{
    public int usageKey { get; set; }
    public string scientificName { get; set; }
    public string canonicalName { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int confidence { get; set; }
    public string matchType { get; set; }
    public string kingdom { get; set; }
    public string phylum { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public string genus { get; set; }
    public string species { get; set; }
    public int kingdomKey { get; set; }
    public int phylumKey { get; set; }
    public int classKey { get; set; }
    public int orderKey { get; set; }
    public int familyKey { get; set; }
    public int genusKey { get; set; }
    public int speciesKey { get; set; }
    public bool synonym { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}
```

After that, we can now access the class properties to that object as usual.

```
    public static List<string> GetOrganismList(string link)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
        var client = new RestClient(link);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var listOrganism = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Organism>(response.Content);

        returnList.Add(" Kingdom: " + listOrganism.kingdom.ToString());
        returnList.Add(" Phylum: " + listOrganism.phylum.ToString());
        returnList.Add(" Order: " + listOrganism.order.ToString());
        returnList.Add(" Family: " + listOrganism.family.ToString());
        returnList.Add(" Genus: " + listOrganism.genus.ToString());
        returnList.Add(" Species: " + listOrganism.species.ToString());

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: A couple of notes: Visual Studio's `Paste Special` tool works when the JSON structure is very simple (like in this case). When it's not, the results are not exactly reliable. There are on-line resource that perform a much better *analysis*. At this time, [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) (not affiliated in any way) is probably the most significant. -- Your properties (`listOrganism.kingdom` and the others you're considering here) are already strings, so you don't need `.ToString()`. Not that much important, it's just redundant.