# In case of nested objects, how can I access a property of top level object from the nested object?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

```
let x = {
    name:"vin1",
    oi:this,
    ob:{
        name:"vin2",
        ob1:{
            name:'vin3',
            ob2:{
                name:"vin4",
                func:function(){
                    console.log(name);  //  I want to access the name "vin1" here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184536/9186194) answer which says it's not natively supported in JS.
Any way to access the outer object property from the inner object?

Comment: `x.name`, as shown in the third answer. If you don't have a reference to the top level object already, then there isn't really anything you can do

Comment: @CertainPerformance How can I get the reference to the top level object in the inner object?

Comment: *If you don't have a reference to the top level object already, then there isn't really anything you can do*

Comment: Wow! I was so fixated on getting the value by going up the ladder that I forgot I can access 'x' directly in the console.log().. Thanks @CertainPerformance